# Modifying viewer.js file

Tags: javascript, mozilla, pdf.js

According to Mozilla's pdfjs plugin, I can view my pdfs by passing a query param to [viewer.html](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) as shown below:

```
http://localhost/MyProject/viewer.html/?file=file.pdf
```

This is working fine. But I have some different kind of requirement. The requirement in my project is that I need to have tabs like feature on a single page. Each tab holds a pdf file.

So, I am thinking to make all the code in the `viewer.js` to a big function. So that I can use it as constructor to render each pdf file. Something like this:

```
var firstPdf = new paintPdf({file: 'myfile.pdf'});
```

Anyway, I decided to do the above changes later when I am able to integrate pdfjs's viewer functionality successfully in my project.

***Summary of my project***:

- Single page application
- All templates are being maintained in a single file within an Object of name - `templates`

To do so, first of all, I copied all the html inside of the body tag of `viewer.html` and appended as new property to the `templates` object. and then I copied all necessary and dependency files from the example to my project's folder and loaded them dynamically. The files which I included are:

- pdf.js
- pdf.worker.js
- viewer.js
- l10n.js
- viewer.css - *I am not loading this file dynamically.*

After loading of files, I am rendering the `viewer.html`'s template using `lodash`. Still, I can't able to see the rendered pdf in my project. I suspect this might be because everything is happening dynamically. (*but I am not sure because everything is being rendered in sequence as it should be*)

Btw, I have added the default pdf with name `compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf` adjacent to `index.html` file. What could I be missing?

Firefox and chrome doesn't throw any error.

Note: I might be doing in wrong way. Suggesting me to solve in right directions would be appreciable.

Comment: @downvoter will be better if you explain the downvote.

Comment: I think down vote was bc question doesn't give nearly enough info. I understand the gist of your Q but without the implementation of your object I wouldn't guess what could be wrong.

Comment: Have you considered using an `<iframe>` to render the PDFs?

Comment: @SteveH. yes I had. I actually kind of solved it. I can't remove the bounty now.

Comment: You can answer your own questions. Just add an answer and explain your solution.

Comment: @SteveH. Will definitely do when I have time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some important points while modifying `viewer.js`.

- It is recommended to build your own `viewer.js` instead of modifying the available `viewer.js` file which is actually just for demo purpose.
- You can create your own viewer.js file by visiting each js files [available here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/web).

If you have only small things to modify in the existing demo `viewer.js`, then

- Mention the exact path for `pdf.worker.js` file inside your `viewer.js`.
- This file will start rendering pdf on `DomContentLoaded` event. If you are planning to render the pdf file dynamically later, then you should comment this event register and call the following function whenever necessary.

  ```
  webViewerLoad();
  ```

I hope this will help someone.

Comment: Could you please provide info on how to create our own custom viewer in Angular?

Comment: Hey, it should be the same.. as I explained the JavaScript way. Angular is just on top of JavaScript.

Comment: I am having difficulty in bringing up pdfjs in angular without wrapper. Can we meet if you have sometime. I want to understand how to integrate other files on top of pdfdist

Comment: @user3660375 I don't think I remember much as this is 6 years before. I am not working on Angular from 4 years now.